# array_key_exists - key does exist but it returns nothing, totally stumped

Tags: php

I am trying to return an array key from an array which does exist but it keeps on returning nothing. This is the var_dump I did, key is there as can be seen clearly, no spaces or funny characters either that might lead to a false. Array is called client -

```
array (size=12)
'mark' => string 'toyota' (length=6)
'catalog_code' => string '19' (length=2)
'family' => string 'AVENSIS' (length=7)
'model' => string 'AVENSIS' (length=7)
'ssd' => string '0838923013ef360e58e50880d14168cf:150fee3cf189d9a0dafa776be4blabla' (length=65)
'param' => string '' (length=0)
'modification' => string '' (length=0)
'group' => string '' (length=0)
'subgroup' => string '' (length=0)
'universal_classifier' => string 'yes' (length=3)
'vin' => string 'SB1BJ56L30Eblabla' (length=17)
'frame' => string '' (length=0)
```

This was my original code which returned nothing, also no errors -

```
$arrvin = array($datret["client"]);
var_dump($datret["client"]);
if (array_key_exists('vin',$arrvin))
{ 
    $vin = $datret["client"]["vin"];
    $_SESSION['vin'] = $vin;
    echo $_SESSION['vin'];
    echo "<br />";
    echo $vin;
}
else
{
    $_SESSION['vin'] = "No Vehicle V.I.N. Captured";
    echo "No key found - vin.";
}
```

I get the echo - No key found - vin as a return. I have also tried trim to check for spaces etc, also no luck. If I run the code without the array_key_exists if statement, I get the vin number from the array.

```
$arrvin = array($datret["client"]);
var_dump($datret["client"]);
    $vin = $datret["client"]["vin"];
    $_SESSION['vin'] = $vin;
    echo $_SESSION['vin'];
    echo "<br />";
    echo $vin;
```

This returns the data, no problem. Anyone have an idea where I am going wrong please?

Comment: why do you add `array` to `$arrvin = array($datret["client"]);` ? `$datret["client"]` is array. Just use `$arrvin = $datret["client"];`

Comment: $arrvin has only one key and this key is 0. $datret["client"] has the key 'vin'

Comment: Have you tried inspecting `$arrvin`?

Comment: Thank you all, I am testing options now.

Comment: Solved, thanks V-K. Not sure what the down-vote was for from someone that will rather add a down-vote than to supply the community with a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$datret["client"]` is associate array. Then you do `$arrvin = array($datret["client"]), you put this array inside new one. So the structure will be like this:

```
$arrvin = [
    0 => [
      //all data here
    ]
 ];
```

Try this to get data:

```
$arrvin = $datret["client"];
if (array_key_exists('vin', $arrvin)) { 
    $vin = $datret["client"]["vin"];
    $_SESSION['vin'] = $vin;
    echo $_SESSION['vin'];
    echo "<br />";
    echo $vin;
} else {
    $_SESSION['vin'] = "No Vehicle V.I.N. Captured";
    echo "No key found - vin.";
}
```

Comment: Maybe try to explain what his mistake is and not just "Hey copy-paste this and will work'

Comment: @V-K - thank you for explanation, this was so obvious yet I missed it, never saw that I am creating an array inside an array, quite stupid. Thank you for the fix, it works perfect!!!